# Create instance from generic class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following classes :

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TIdentifier> : IRepository<TEntity, TIdentifier> where TEntity : class
{ --- }

public abstract class BaseBusinessObject<TEntity, TIdentifier> : Repository<TEntity, TIdentifier> where TEntity : class
    { --- }

public class AttachmentBusinessObject : BaseBusinessObject<Attachment, long>
    { --- }
```

Somewhere, The only things that I have are **"AttachmentBusinessObject"** in string and **"Attachment"** as `TEntity` in string.

How can I create an instance of `BaseBusinessObject` or `AttachmentBusinessObject` ?

Comment: `BaseBusinessObject` is an abstract class, you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: So,How we can create instance from `AttachmentBusinessObject` ?

Comment: @Mohammad: using reflection? Trough the `Activator`. Look at the duplicate question for a lot more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your correctly, but you may want to check out [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

Something like this:

```
var yourObject
    = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "AttachmentBusinessObject").Unwrap();
```

This isn't very useful though, if you want to pass the object around, because `CreateInstance` has no idea what the type might be, so it just returns an `object`.

One way around it - any classes you'll be creating an instance of can all implement a common interface. So you might end up with something like:

```
IBusinessObject yourObject
    = (IBusinessObject)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "AttachmentBusinessObject").Unwrap();
```

Another option is to use the first line of code above, and then test for the correct class type in an if/else statement:

```
Type objType = yourObject.GetType();

if (objType == typeof(AttachmentBusinessObject))
{
    var myAttachBusObject = (AttachmentBusinessObject)yourObject;
    ...
}
else
    ...
```

Comment: Can we cast `yourObject` to `BaseBusinessObject`, If so how ? I have to convert `yourObject` to `BaseBusinessObject` for using its methods

Comment: I have several `BusinessObject`s class in my project, I have to write if statement for each of them ?  e.g: `ContentBusinessObject`, `BrandBusinessObject`, ... Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class Base
{ }

public class Derived : Base
{ }

[TestMethod]
public void BaseDerivedTest()
{
    string type = "Derived"; // type is found somewhere upstream
    if (type == "Derived")
    {
        var b = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Derived).BaseType);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(b, typeof(Base));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your solution doesn't work in my sample, because I have to cast b to `BaseBusinessObject` for using its methods

Comment: I don't see how it couldn't work for you. I made an edit for clarity. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I have several `BusinessObject`s class in my project instead of `"Derived"`, I have to write if statement for each of them ? e.g: `ContentBusinessObject`, `BrandBusinessObject`, ... Is there a better way?